# How to determine the exact measure of the vertical space added in front of \maketitle?

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir, titles

How would I get `\maketitle` to not add any vertical space before the title? The memoir manual (p.65) says:

> The \maketitle command puts the title at a particular height on the
> page. You can change the vertical position of the title via the length
> \droptitle . Giving this a positive value will lower the title and a
> negative value will raise it.

"at a particular height" probably means that this depends on a number of factors, such that it is not the same in different circumstances. But how would I go about finding out exactly how much it is in my case? Is there any better method than trial and error?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setlength{\droptitle}{0pt}
\author{Me}
\title{Something}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text also.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
% droptitleprob.tex  SE 552139

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\LARGE\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}\normalsize
\addtolength{\droptitle}{-1.5\baselineskip}
\author{Me}
\title{Something}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text also.
 
\lipsum{1,2}

\end{document}
```

The lengths are cribbed from the `memoir.cls` code and put the first line of the title at the same height as the first line of text on the following page.